# How to change IGN in play store?

Tags: google-play-store

Before, I had a coc acc and I got bored so I gave my acc (gmail) to my friend. My friend then changed the ign to his name. Now that i got a new phone, I installed coc and even if my old acc is already installed, i cannot play my old acc and his ign appears at the top. How can I change my ign?  Do I need to log out my acc from his phone?

Comment: If you have two gmail accounts and want to use both of them in clash of clans you need to go to Google play games and for both accounts go to settings and uncheck "Sign in to gamed automatically" and "use this account to sign in" than clear data for game and it will ofer you to chosse between accounts. And one more thing changing name in clash of clans is possible only once.

Answer (score 0):

To change your IGN

- Open **Google Play Games**.
- Tap the IGN
- Tap on the Pencil in the top right
- Change the IGN.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think it's easy only you need to follow this step...
Go to settings->accounts->add account->and add another Google account with the new email. Then go into the play store and there will be your email with a drop down arrow. Tap it and select the new email.